# How to count elements in a text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to count elements in a text file. I know I am missing an obvious part, but I can't put my finger on it. This is what I currently have which just produces the count of the letter "f" not the file:

```
filename = open("output3.txt")
f = open("countoutput.txt", "w")
import collections
for line in filename: 
    for number in line.split(): 
        print(collections.Counter("f"))
        break
```

Comment: can you share a sample of your file? Also you code compute the number of "f" letter per line; you want to have the total count of "f" in all the file?

Comment: Chemical elements?

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter()  # create a new counter
with open(filename) as infile:  # open the file for reading
    for line in infile: 
        for number in line.split(): 
            counts.update((number,))
            print("Now there are {} instances of {}".format(counts[number], number))
print(counts)
```

Comment: a few comments or lines of explanation would probably go a long way for an apparently new user of python..

Comment: @Aaron I've just never had to use the Counter function

Comment: @H.Minear It's good for anyone else with a similar question as well, even if you can understand just by reading the code..